# show that f is constant on I

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be defined on the interval $I$. all we know about $f$ is that there is a constant $K\gt 0$ so that $|f(a)-f(b)|\le K|a-b|^2$ for all $a$,$b$ on $I$.

Q: show that $f$ is constant on $I$

hint: start with calculating the derivative using the definition?

how do I go about differentiating this inequality using the definition, and can I use $a=x$ and $b=x+h$ ? if yes then how

Comment: Yes, you can, and it is a good idea.  We get $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\le Kh^2$. Divide by $h$.

Comment: Hmm,  I could be completely wrong here,  but you aren't given that f is differentiable.  Does that not pose a difficulty in calculating the deriviative, as it assumes it exists?.  Addendum:  It's not actually a problem, seeing the work below,  you just have to add one line to prove the derivative exists, bound it below by 0 and use the squeeze theorem

Comment: @Alan Yes, part of the problem involves proving that the derivative exists.  But this isn't difficult.  Or, this problem can also be done entirely without calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned $$\lim_{h \to 0} |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}| \le \lim _{h \to 0} k|h| $$

Conclude from here .

Comment: RHS should be $k|h|$, to be precise.

Comment: @abpoir123 Familiar with the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @abpoir123 yes!!!

Comment: @abpoir123. . you don't need $-k|h|$ as the $|\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}|$ is always $\ge 0$. Hence after taking the limit the value will also be $\ge 0$.